# Flutter TextFormField text hidded on overflow

Tags: flutter

When I reach the limit of the **TextFormField** the text disapear...
I tryed multiple config but still not working, I dont find why.

[image]

```dart
Dialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0)), //this right here
        child: Container(
            height: 400.0,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: new Align(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.blue),
                          Text('Test')
                        ])),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
                child: new Align(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
                    child: TextFormField(
                        initialValue: _inputs[0],
                        onChanged: (text) {
                          _inputs[0] = text;
                          checkOkEnabled();
                        },
                        autocorrect: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Mme  / M',
                            hintText: 'test'))),
              )),]))))
```

Same problem on two device : 
[image]

And **Error** field get hidded on strange way too.

The **Expanded** is in a **Container** with a height of 400.

Comment: Detecting the error is hard this way, can you drop your whole Page code?

Comment: I can't :/ the TextFormField is in Dialog, can it change something ?

I will try to make a minimal to reproduce

Comment: a SimpleDialog?

Comment: I add u more code, it's callled with "showDialog" function

Comment: So I just ran your code and it worked fine here...

Comment: I will try on another device, I run it on Nexus 5x API 28

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi try to add 3 more Expanded block (I can't edit stack said that there is too much code in post)

Comment: Worked fine with 3....but I added 6 more and I can now experience the issue

Comment: Yes i think it depend of the size of the screen.

Comment: Maybe would be better to not resize the dialog when the keyboard go up, I dont know if is that possiblen the best would be to scrool the Dialog up or down without change it size.

Comment: @OOM Did you find the solution for this problem? I have the same issue. Help me if you can.

Comment: @RaghuMudem Hello, I think its a problem of height space. Then I just forget about putting fields into a dialog box and I made a page for that to let the fields able to use the space that they needs.
Hope this will be fixed

Comment: @OOM thanks for reply. Yes you are right. I also fixed changing the height.

Answer (score 4):

in `InputDecoration`, add `isDense: true` and `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero`

Answer (score 3):

You are reducing the height of TextFormField from its actual height to something lesser. It happens normally because of additional padding. try to identify that and remove