# Flutter TextFormField text crops when width exceeds

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I am using TextFormField for my flutter application search field.
When i type a text bigger that the width of textformfield, then entered text it cropped to half an not visible completely.
Please find my below code and attached image for more understanding of problem.

```
TextFormField(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      controller: textController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
        ),
        hintText: AppStrings.searchCatHint,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 17,),
      ),
      autovalidate: true,
      autocorrect: false,
      autofocus: true,
    );
```

Screen for problem:

[image]

Similar problem i have seen in another question also, but no solution provided.
[Similar issue link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764160/flutter-textformfield-text-hidded-on-overflow)

Text display proper with @CarlosSR suggestion. But alignment issue as below.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to set TextFormField( maxLines: 1)? it seems to be adding your extra text on a second line

Comment: @CarlosSR Yes, i tried but not working.

Comment: what if you wrap your TextFormField in a SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal
                      child: TextFormField( maxLines:1, ...))

Comment: It would be good, if we type new letter the entire text should move to left. But not finding how to do it.

Comment: @CarlosSR i will try your approach.

Comment: I m unable to reproduce the error. can you show your code?

Comment: @SandeepSharma code i mentioned above. And if you type more letters in textformfield, It will display text as cropped as displayed in attached screen.

Comment: @CarlosSR with your approach it is displaying text properly, But there is another problem with alignment. Please check the attachment.

Comment: I would guess your TextFormField is wrapped in a row or something. Provide full code so people could help you

Comment: Yes, the error will occur when you wrap textformfield with padding.

Comment: My code is like AppBar(child: above widget); there is now more intermediate code.

Comment: please use Wrap widget around textformfield

Comment: @Jaimil Patel, Warp also fixed text crop issue but it has the same alignment issue. This i am not able provide the solution. After using the wrap result is same as 2nd screen attached in the question.

Comment: Finally my issue has addressed. This comment to to specify the problem and resolution. 
Problem: On enter new text, old text should move to left without any problem.

Solution: I have specified a height for my TextFormField with Wrapping with Container. Code is Container(height:40, child: TextFormFiled(...));   

This worked for me!! Thanks alot for all you responses.

Comment: @RaghuMudem Have you got the solution for moving the text to left when new character is added to the long text in the Textfield, so that the letter added comes in vicinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the issue.

Problem description: On entering new text, old text should move to left without any problem.

Solution: I have specified a height for my TextFormField with Wrapping with Container. Code looks like below.

```
Container(
height:40, 
child: TextFormFiled(...),
);
```

This worked for me. Thanks a lot for all your responses.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping textformfield with container:

error will not occur:

```
Container(
            color: Colors.black12,
            width: 280,
            height: 45,
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                ),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 17,),
              ),
              autovalidate: true,
              autocorrect: false,
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
```

error is with padding I guess if you are using:

```
Container(
            color: Colors.black12,
            width: 280,
            height: 45,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                  ),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,),
                ),
                autovalidate: true,
                autocorrect: false,
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can only scroll the widget in horizontal axis, plus you add a padding to get your text in the position you want. In other, I recommend you to check for Align widget.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
child: TextFormField(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      controller: textController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
        ),
        hintText: AppStrings.searchCatHint,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 17,),
      ),
      autovalidate: true,
      autocorrect: false,
      autofocus: true,
    ),
),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I too happend to have the exact issue.The thing that i noticed that when i have a textfield in an container of some hardcoded height you might encounter this issue.Try removing the height of the container or just remove the textfields bottom padding.This will help.

Comment: Hi Rutvik and Vinay,
Problem has been solved. The solution i have mentioned in the comment section of my question. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is using the `CupertinoTextField` widget. You can read about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTextField-class.html).